# How to fit text in container properly

Tags: react-native

As you see in pic below, text goes put of the container component, I expect it to wrap new line,

Tried

[image]

component;

```
<Card style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,5)', elevation: 2 }} shadow>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                            <Avatar
                                size="large"
                                rounded
                                icon={{ name: 'home' }}
                                
                                source={{
                                    uri:
                                        'http://imageurl',
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }} activeOpacity={.5}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                                    marginBottom: 10,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: colors.primary
                                }}>LABEL:
                            </Text>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    paddingLeft: 5,
                                    color: colors.black
                                }}>adasdasd asdasd asdasdsad asdasdsad SOME LONG TEXT!! asdasdsad</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: colors.black
                                }}>Ort. Puan:
                            </Text>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    paddingLeft: 5,
                                    color: colors.black
                                }}>4.2
                            </Text>

                            </View>

                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: colors.black
                                }}>Adres:
                            </Text>
                                <Text style={{
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    paddingLeft: 5,
                                    color: colors.black
                                }}>Ayaş yolu Bulvarı, Sincan asdasd SOME LONG TEXT!!
                            </Text>

                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Card>
```

How to make text fit in the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code and changed `flexDirection:'column'` and added `flex:1`  to long texts.. you can add `flex:1` rest your text components if they might expand in future.

```
<Card
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,5)', elevation: 2 }}
      shadow
    >
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Avatar.Image source={require('../assets/snack-icon.png')} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 ,flex:1 }} activeOpacity={0.5}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                marginBottom: 10,
                fontSize: 16,
                color: 'red',
              }}
            >
              LABEL:
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                paddingLeft: 5,
                color: 'black',
                flex:1
              }}
            >
              adasdasd asdasd asdasdsad asdasdsad SOME LONG TEXT!! asdasdsad
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                fontSize: 16,
                color: 'red',
              }}
            >
              Ort. Puan:
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                paddingLeft: 5,
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              4.2
            </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: 'AsapCondensed-Bold',
                fontSize: 16,
                color: 'red',
              }}
            >
              Adres:
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                paddingLeft: 5,
                color: 'black',
                flex:1
              }}
            >
              Ayaş yolu Bulvarı, Sincan asdasd SOME LONG TEXT!!
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Card>
```

check screen shot of given code.
[image]